# underscore.js not working with < and > in html

Tags: javascript, html, underscore.js

I'm working with underscore.js and i'm having problems with < and > in `<%= name %>`. They're automatically replaced by &lt ; and &gt ; and that causes my code not to work.

My index.html:

```
<div id="underscore">
   <%= name %>
</div>
```

My script:

```
var source   = $("#underscore").html();

var compiled = _.template(source);
var html = compiled({name: 'pepe'});
$("#underscore").html(html);
```

I fixed the problem adding to my script this lines (before var compiled) and works fine

```
source = source.replace("&lt;","<");
source = source.replace("&gt;",">");
```

Is there any other way to solve my problem?

Comment: what text editor are you using?

Comment: i wouldn't use a div to hold your template.

Comment: The problem is that the contents of a `<div>` element are going to be assumed by the browser to be HTML markup that you want it to interpret and, implicitly, fix if it's not fully valid.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Conventionally people use `<script>` tags with non-JavaScript "type" attributes to embed templates.

```
<script id=underscore type=text/underscore>
  <%= name %>
</script>
```

The browser will completely ignore everything up to the closing `</script>` tag.  You'll still be able to fetch it as the `.innerHTML` of the `<script>`.

Comment: [additionally, the new `template` element is meant for exactly this purpose](http://www.w3.org/html/wg/drafts/html/master/single-page.html#the-template-element).

Comment: @zzzzBov well that's interesting, but I don't think it's quite the same thing. A `<template>` element is supposed to be associated with a DOM fragment, so it's still supposed to contain just valid HTML markup. With JavaScript template systems, sometimes that's not what you want. (I realize that itself is a religious issue to some :)